# Smalltalk Error handling with Transcript

Tags: error-handling, smalltalk, pharo

Suppose I have the following method:

```
MyClass>>addCategory: aCategory toEvent: anEvent
    | cat |
    cat := anEvent addCategory: aCategory
    ...
```

Now, the method `#addCategory` can either return some other object (e.g. something of class `Foo`) or throw an error (using `Error signal: 'message'`).

- In case of an error, I would like to print the message of the error on the Transcript.
- In case of an object, I would like to print some message on the Transcript (e.g. `Transcript show: 'Category added!'`) and return the object.

I have been looking at `aBlock ifError: aBlock`, something like this:

```
MyClass>>addCategory: aCategory toEvent: anEvent
    | cat |
    cat := [anEvent addCategory: aCategory] ifError: [ :err | Transcript show: err. ]
    ...
```

But I can't quite figure out how to handle the variable `cat` afterwards, in order to get the behavior I want.

Comment: What behavior do you want? What do you want `cat` to be in the case of no error versus error?

Comment: @lurker In case of no error, `cat` will be of class `Foo` and I want to return it. In case of an error, I just want to print the error. I no longer need `cat` in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do the same. The idea is to enclose your code as if would not fail and wrap it with an `on: Error`

```
MyClass>>addCategory: aCategory toEvent: anEvent
  | cat |
  [
    cat := anEvent addCategory: aCategory.
    Transcript show: 'Category added!']
    on: Error
    do: [:err | Transcript show: err messageText].
 ^cat
```

Notice that `cat` will not get assigned in case of `Error` and hence the method will answer with `nil`. Notice also that there is no need to `^nil` from within the error-handler block.

Remember that the idea of `on:do:` is to allow you to write naïve code and then handle possible error conditions without inlining them into the error-free section of your code.

```
[
 <my naive
 and clean
 lines of code>] on: Error do: [:err | oops!]
```

Your solution is ok but inlines error handling code inside the main code, making it a little bit harder for the reader to get the main idea of the relevant code.

Comment: This is indeed better than my solution! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this is the following:

```
MyClass>>addCategory: aCategory toEvent: anEvent
    | cat |
    cat := [ anEvent addCategory: aCategory] on: Error do [ :err | Transcript show: err messageText. ^nil. ]
    Transcript show: 'Category added!'.
    ^cat
```

This solution will print the error to the Transcript and return `nil` from the method. In case there is no error, the code will continue, print the message on the Transcript and return the object.

This might not be the best solution, but it is one possible way of doing it. As long as you don't mind that `nil` is returned in case of an error.